# Validating SAML tokens

Tags: authentication, saml, sts-securitytokenservice

I am writing a Client and Service using Axis2 and rampart
A third party authenticator which I will control as well will issue a token to the client in which the client will send to the service
The problem is I have no idea how to validate this token, I was told it is outside of the scope of SAML
Is there a way to validate the token without contacting the third party authenticator or without using public keys

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [example of Apache WSS4J](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/xref-test/org/apache/ws/security/saml/SamlTokenTest.html) (which I believe is compatible with rampart, haven't used rampart myself). They use a [`CustomSamlAssertionValidator`](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/xref-test/org/apache/ws/security/common/CustomSamlAssertionValidator.html) which appears to just compare the name of the issuer in the SAML token to pre-defined value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
But I couldn't find more information than the class
I want to know if public key is used, or any hash functions because I need to write a report on the entire implementation system

Comment: Well, post the token as issued by your STS (that's the third party authenticator you mentioned, right?) to see if it uses public key crypto. Why don't you want to use public keys anyway?

Comment: I don't mind using public key for signatures, but I am writing a paper on this so I have to write about all the ways that this can be done in, then decide on the most efficient one for our case
The most important part for me is that the SAML token must carries a symmetric key to both the client and server secretly